# How would someone install and compile gcc C on a usb

Tags: c, bash, cmd, usb

I want to program at my school in my free time, but the compilers they have are buggy. I want to use gcc. The rules at my school say that I cannot install anything on the desktops there. I was thinking about installing gcc on a usb then I would use a bash emulator to compile the files. Would this work and if not how would I do it then?

Comment: Try the keyword `U3` for portable applications for USB when searching. Also see here... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_portable_software and also here... http://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/files/Portable%20Releases/

Comment: It would be helpful to say what platform the computers at your school use (Windows, Mac OS X, ???). I suppose it is Windows since you mention a bash emulator, but the question needs to make it clear. Also, it would be very useful to know what system you have available to create the USB. Finally, out of curiosity, why do you think the compilers are buggy? What compilers are they, exactly?

Comment: The computers use windows 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm using this whenever I need to code on a laptop/PC i don't own : https://code.google.com/p/pocketcpp/
It compiles C and C++

Comment: You said it compiled C, I went to the site and it only referenced c++ code snippets. Are you sure it compiles C. C is all I know.

Comment: Yeah sure, G++ compile C as well